# Jupyter-notebook fails to start | PyForMLS

Tags: jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service

I am currently setting up a Python data-science client for SQL Server Machine Learning Services following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/python/setup-python-client-tools-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Unfortunately, running Jupyter notebooks for this distribution does not seem to work for me: Typing `.\Scripts\jupyter-notebook` in the distribution folder, or directly running jupyter-notebook.exe from the Scripts sub-folder does not start Jupyter. In the terminal, the command exits with no ouput.
Afterwards, https://localhost:8889/tree is not reachable as should be the case according to the tutorial above.

Any suggestions? (I already checked https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html for solutions). Thank you!

---

Update: At least `.\Scripts\jupyter-console` is running, though it is not the same experience.

Answer (score 0):

some cases `.\Scripts\jupyter-notebook` will not work fine because of the installation issues. As anaconda is having both commercial and enterprise editions, issues will raise.

Instead use the following procedure for cool opening of `Jupyter-Notebook` in `anaconda distribution`

1. Click on Start menu
2. Type Jupyter
3. Click on jupter icon which is visible in search results
4. Jupyter CMD will start running and make it minimized instead closing it. It will open the UI of jupyter notebook in browser.

**Jupyter notebook for SQL**
Check the documentation link which is available in [link](https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-jupyter-notebooks-for-sql-server/) which is the configuration of jupyter notebook for SQL.

Document Credit: [Rajendra Gupta](https://www.sqlshack.com/author/rajendra-gupta/)

```
 https://localhost:8889/tree
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried - perhaps I should add that I have another Anaconda installation which I use for my other Python projects. So the Jupyter notebook from this Anaconda distribution is working. This Jupyter can probably not be connected to the ML for SQL Server Python/Anaconda distribution (kernel mismatch)? Unfortunately, the jupyter notebook from the ML for SQL Server Python/Anaconda distribution does also not run by clicking the related icons found by searching the start menu.

Comment: Kindly check the updated answer at the end of the section.